# Is max_inflight_messages bi-direction or only one way limit?

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

I am curious about if the `max_inflight_messages` is bi-direction or only one way limit.

If set the `max_inflight_messages` to 1 and client subscribed qos 2. While client is receiving a message, does that means client cannot send any message at the same time? and vise versa?

Reference: http://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto-conf-5.html

> max_inflight_messages count
>
> The maximum number of QoS 1 or 2 messages that can be in the process
>   of being transmitted simultaneously. This includes messages currently
>   going through handshakes and messages that are being retried. Defaults
>   to 20. Set to 0 for no maximum. If set to 1, this will guarantee
>   in-order delivery of messages.
>
> Reloaded on reload signal.